# getWebView() error in tutorial #9

Tags: commonsware

I created the AbstractContentFragment object following the instructions for tutorial #9. After copying in the code from the book I get the error "The method getWebView() is undefined for the type AbstractContentFragment"

I have checked the code - it is exactly what is in the book.
I have the actionbarsherlock library included in the project - no issues with Tutorial #8.
I can see the getWebview() method in the webviewfragment class.

Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

> I have checked the code - it is exactly what is in the book

Pretty much, by definition, it is not.

> I can see the getWebview() method in the webviewfragment class.

Presumably, your `AbstractContentFragment` is not extending `WebViewFragment`. This is covered in Step #3 of Tutorial #9 (at least in Version 4.5 of the book -- different book editions may have slightly different editions of the tutorial).

Comment: that is the point i get the error. I have created the file using the code supplied and get the error on these 3 lines:

Comment: getWebView().getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
getWebView().getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
getWebView().getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
getWebView().loadUrl(getPage());

Comment: @user2004698: Did you read my answer? If so, please modify your `AbstractContentFragment` to inherit from `WebViewFragment`. That is how it is in the book. That is is how it is in the GitHub repo.

Comment: @user200469 - i apreciate the feedback. i did check and that exactly what i have and why i am so baffled. my code matches the code in the book:
abstract public class AbstractContentFragment extends WebViewFragment {

so now i am off to pull the file from github...

Comment: @user2004698: You are welcome to upload your code somewhere, that we can take a look at in its entirety.

Comment: ok - closed all project files and re-opend and all is well. thanks.

Comment: @user2004698: That is rather strange. Are you editing files both inside and outside of Eclipse? (BTW, I am assuming you are using Eclipse) If so, bear in mind that Eclipse does not see outside-of-Eclipse changes until you refresh the project (press <F5> on the directory that contains the changes in the Package Explorer).